# Prevent simultaneous login from multiple machines

Tags: authentication

Here is a scenario where you need smart cards to login to your application. Sometimes your application may be offline (ie. no internet connection). For that I can still get the user to use the software with his smart card because the smart card has been registered in the application (remember: you can only register a smart card on to your application when the system is online. once the smart card is registered with your application you can access/login to your application even if your system is offline.) But my problem is that incase the user registers the smart card onto the application in more than one computer, he will be able to simultaneously use all the computers at the same time.
I want to know if it is possible to restrict the user to use only one computer/application at a time. The application saves data from a user/system when he gets online perhaps once in a day or a week. But here the application will synchronize data from all computers. I want to prevent that. What is the possible solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should allow registration with a smart card only when online. 
When the user tries to register on another computer, check if the user has been authenticated on another machine previously.
If false, then go on with registering.
If true, then you go 2 different ways.
1. The other machine is online. Unregister from that other machine and register to the new one.
2. The other machine is not online. Registering on this machine should not be possible.

Comment: Hi George, Thanks a lot for the solution...Great Idea!

Comment: But George, what if the other system where the smart card had been registered cannot get online or switched on due to some maintainence issue?

Comment: Then, for safety reasons, the user will not be able to register on new machine.